# Multiplicative structure on spectra with coefficients

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For any spectrum $E$ we can define "spectrum with coefficients in $G$" by $EG := E \wedge MG$, where $MG$ is the Moore spectrum of type $G$.

If $E$ is an $A_{\infty}$ (resp. $E_{\infty})$ ring spectrum, will $EG$ also be $A_{\infty}$ (resp. $E_{\infty})$? If not in general, are there any specific conditions under which that might be true (e.g. $G$ finite etc)?

Thank you for any references!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but rather just an example.

Let $MC_2$ be the mod 2 Moore spectrum.  Notably, it is [not a ring spectrum](https://mathoverflow.net/q/87919), so even though $E = \mathbb{S}$ is $E_\infty$, the spectrum $\mathbb{S}C_2 \simeq MC_2$ is not a ring spectrum, let alone $A_\infty$ or $E_\infty$.

This shows that in general even if $E$ is a structured ring, $EG$ need not be.  It also shows that the finiteness of $G$ is not the condition you are looking for.

**Added later:** In fact, you can just ask whether Moore spectra are highly structured.  It turns out that it is generally not the case.  For example, they are never $E_\infty$, and that for many $G$ they are known to not be $A_\infty$.  See the answers on this [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/175951) for details.